# How to calculate statistic values over 2D DataFrame bin wise for column ranges defined via IntervalIndex?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've a 2D DataFrame like follows

```
  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  ...
0 0    1    NaN  3    4
1 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9
...
```

. For every row I'd like to calculate the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) and the [arithmetic standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) for specific, equal width column ranges (bins) which shall be defined via `IntervalIndex`. `NaN` shall be ignored. E.g. with `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0.0, 0.2), (0.2, 0.4)]` I'd expect something like

```
     (0.0, 0.2)  (0.2, 0.4)
mean 0.          3.5
std  ...
```

The intervals shall support different widths. As the DataFrame has many rows and many columns memory and execution performance is critical. How can I get my expected output as performant as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a cut, and groupby:

```
df.columns=df.columns.astype(float)
cuts = pd.cut(df.columns, bins=[0, 0.2, 0.4],include_lowest=True)

df.groupby(cuts, axis=1).mean()
```

Output:

```
   (-0.001, 0.2]  (0.2, 0.4]
0            0.5         3.5
1            NaN         9.0
```

**Note:** you can also pass `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0.0, 0.2), (0.2, 0.4)])` to `bins` in `pd.cut`, if you already have them defined somewhere. But you need to be careful about `0`, which is not included in the intervals above.

**Note 2:** it appears that `groupby().agg` does not support `std` on `axis=1`. You can transform the dataframe:

```
df.T.groupby(cuts).agg(['mean','std']).T
```

Output:

```
        (-0.001, 0.2]  (0.2, 0.4]
0 mean       0.500000    3.500000
  std        0.707107    0.707107
1 mean            NaN    9.000000
  std             NaN         NaN
```

Comment: I used `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples` to pass intervals but got `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`. Seems like your solution does only work if all interval bound values are present in the initial dataframe.

Comment: Did you pass `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples` into `pd.cut` or `groupby()`?

Comment: BTW: How can I define the output dataframe for unit testing?

Comment: A dataframe with `columns= pd.CategoricalIndex(pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(100.5, 101.5)]), ordered=True)`, `data= [[0.5], [3.5], [np.nan], [9.0]]` and `index = [[0, 0, 1, 1], ['mean', 'std', 'mean', 'std']]` is the way to go test driving the implentation.

Comment: `df.T.groupby(cuts).agg(['mean','std']).unstack(level=1)`?