# How to calculate geometric mean and stddev over 2D DataFrame bin wise for column ranges defined via IntervalIndex?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've a 2D DataFrame like follows

```
  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  ...
0 0    1    NaN  1    9
1 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9
...
```

. For every row I'd like to calculate the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) and the [geometric standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation) for specific, equal width column ranges (bins) which shall be defined via `IntervalIndex`. `NaN` as well as `0` shall be ignored. E.g. with `pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0.0, 0.2), (0.2, 0.4)]` I'd expect something like

```
        (0.0, 0.2]  (0.2, 0.4]
0 gmean 0.          3
  gstd  ...         ...
1 gmean ...
  gstd
```

In case I would like to calculate the **arithmetic mean and arithmetic standard deviation** I could use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
    data=[[0, 1, np.nan, 1, 9],
          [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9]]
)

bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0.0, 0.2), (0.2, 0.4)])

def mean_and_std(df, bins):
    cuts = pd.cut(df.columns, bins, include_lowest=True)
    return df.T.groupby(cuts).agg(['mean', 'std']).T

mean_and_std(df, bins)
```

which would output

```
            (0.0, 0.2]  (0.2, 0.4]
0   mean    1.0         5.000000
    std     NaN         5.656854
1   mean    NaN         9.000000
    std     NaN         NaN
```

But **geometric mean and geometric standard deviation** are not supported by pandas and need to be e.g. taken from scipy, [`scipy.stats.gmean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.gmean.html) and [`scipy.stats.gstd()`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.gstd.html). However `gmean()` and `gstd()` are not supported by pandas [`GroupBy` objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) (in comparison to [GroupBy.mean()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean) and to [GroupBy.std()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std)). Means they do not work with `pandas.DataFrame.agg()` like explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695241/how-to-calculate-statistic-values-over-2d-dataframe-bin-wise-for-column-ranges-d/58695359?noredirect=1#comment103693069_58695359). How can I get my expected output as performant as possible? (As the DataFrame has many rows and many columns memory and execution performance is critical.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695241/how-to-calculate-statistic-values-over-2d-dataframe-bin-wise-for-column-ranges-d/58695359#58695359 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate statistic values over 2D DataFrame bin wise for column ranges defined via IntervalIndex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695241/how-to-calculate-statistic-values-over-2d-dataframe-bin-wise-for-column-ranges-d)

Comment: @ansev No, the other question is about arithmetic mean and std. Here it is about geometric mean and std which are not supported by pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, somebody will improve the answer later.
For now I know that for **geometric mean** you can try QuantStats package:

```
import quantstats as qs
qs.extend_pandas()
pandas_df.geometric_mean()
```

Hope this can help a bit